# Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, expression-trees

I understand lambdas and the `Func` and `Action` delegates. But expressions 
stump me.

In what circumstances would you use an `Expression<Func<T>>` rather than a plain old `Func<T>`?

Comment: Func<> will be converted to a method on the c# compiler level
,Expression<Func<>> will be executed on the MSIL level after compiling the code directly, that is the reason it is faster

Comment: in addition to the answers, the csharp language specification "4.6 expression tree types" is helpful to cross reference

Comment: For anyone wanting to cross-reference with the C# Language Specification: [Expression Tree Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#expression-tree-types)

Answer (score 1315, accepted):

When you want to treat lambda expressions as expression trees and look inside them instead of executing them. For example, LINQ to SQL gets the expression and converts it to the equivalent SQL statement and submits it to server (rather than executing the lambda).

Conceptually, `Expression<Func<T>>` is *completely different* from `Func<T>`. `Func<T>` denotes a `delegate` which is pretty much a pointer to a method and `Expression<Func<T>>` denotes a *tree data structure* for a lambda expression. This tree structure **describes what a lambda expression does** rather than doing the actual thing. It basically holds data about the composition of expressions, variables, method calls, ... (for example it holds information such as this lambda is some constant + some parameter). You can use this description to convert it to an actual method (with `Expression.Compile`) or do other stuff (like the LINQ to SQL example) with it. The act of treating lambdas as anonymous methods and expression trees is purely a compile time thing.

```
Func<int> myFunc = () => 10; // similar to: int myAnonMethod() { return 10; }
```

will effectively compile to an IL method that gets nothing and returns 10.

```
Expression<Func<int>> myExpression = () => 10;
```

will be converted to a data structure that describes an expression that gets no parameters and returns the value 10:

[[image: Expression vs Func] *larger image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwU0E.jpg)

While they both look the same at compile time, what the compiler generates is **totally different**.

Comment: So, in other words, an `Expression` contains the meta-information about a  certain delegate.

Comment: @bertl Actually, no. The delegate is not involved at all. The reason there's any association at all with a delegate is that you can compile the expression *to* a delegate - or to be more precise, compile it to a method and get the delegate to that method as a return value. But the expression tree itself is just data. The delegate does not exist when you use `Expression<Func<...>>` instead of just `Func<...>`.

Comment: You're absolutely right @Luaan. I did not mean to create any artificial relationship between `Expressions` and delegates. My point was related to the original question, i.e. "What does an `Expression<Func<T>>` have and a `Func<T>` not?" I just wanted to summarize the accepted answer in a very brief manner; it may sound a little oversimplified, though.

Comment: This metadata is useful so that you can convert a C# query into a query in any other language. For example, you could convert C# `StartsWith()` into SQL `LIKE '%etc'` . See http://www.codethinked.com/taking-the-magic-out-of-expression

Comment: What makes it a tree? Where are the branches?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney `(isAnExample) => { if(isAnExample) ok(); else expandAnswer(); }` such expression is an ExpressionTree, branches are created for the If-statement.

Comment: @bertl Delegate is what CPU sees (executable code of one architecture), Expression is what compiler sees (merely another format of source code, but still source code).

Comment: @bertl: It might be more accurately summarized by saying that an expression is to a func what a stringbuilder is to a string. It's not a string/func, but it contains the needed data to create one when asked to do so.

Answer (score 477):

I'm adding an answer-for-noobs because these answers seemed over my head, until I realized how simple it is. Sometimes it's your expectation that it's complicated that makes you unable to 'wrap your head around it'.

I didn't need to understand the difference until I walked into a really annoying 'bug' trying to use LINQ-to-SQL generically:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get(Func<T, bool> conditionLambda){
  using(var db = new DbContext()){
    return db.Set<T>.Where(conditionLambda);
  }
}
```

This worked great until I started getting OutofMemoryExceptions on larger datasets. Setting breakpoints inside the lambda made me realize that it was iterating through each row in my table one-by-one looking for matches to my lambda condition. This stumped me for a while, because why the heck is it treating my data table as a giant IEnumerable instead of doing LINQ-to-SQL like it's supposed to? It was also doing the exact same thing in my LINQ-to-MongoDb counterpart.

The fix was simply to turn `Func<T, bool>` into `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so I googled why it needs an `Expression` instead of `Func`, ending up here.

**An expression simply turns a delegate into a data about itself.** So `a => a + 1` becomes something like "On the left side there's an `int a`. On the right side you add 1 to it." **That's it.** You can go home now. It's obviously more structured than that, but that's essentially all an expression tree really is--nothing to wrap your head around.

Understanding that, it becomes clear why LINQ-to-SQL needs an `Expression`, and a `Func` isn't adequate. `Func` doesn't carry with it a way to get into itself, to see the nitty-gritty of how to translate it into a SQL/MongoDb/other query. You can't see whether it's doing addition or multiplication or subtraction. All you can do is run it. `Expression`, on the other hand, allows you to look inside the delegate and see everything it wants to do. This empowers you to translate the delegate into whatever you want, like a SQL query. `Func` didn't work because my DbContext was blind to the contents of the lambda expression. Because of this, it couldn't turn the lambda expression into SQL; however, it did the next best thing and iterated that conditional through each row in my table.

Edit: expounding on my last sentence at John Peter's request:

IQueryable extends IEnumerable, so IEnumerable's methods like `Where()` obtain overloads that accept `Expression`. When you pass an `Expression` to that, you keep an IQueryable as a result, but when you pass a `Func`, you're falling back on the base IEnumerable and you'll get an IEnumerable as a result. In other words, without noticing you've turned your dataset into a list to be iterated as opposed to something to query. It's hard to notice a difference until you really look under the hood at the signatures.

Comment: Chad; Please explain this comment a bit more: "Func didn't work because my DbContext was blind to what was actually in the lambda expression to turn it into SQL, so it did the next best thing and iterated that conditional through each row in my table."

Comment: >> Func... All you can do is run it.

It's not exactly true, but I think that's the point that should be emphasized. Funcs/Actions are to be run, Expressions are to be analyzed (before running or even instead of running).

Comment: @Chad Is the problem here was that?: db.Set<T> queried all the database table, and after, because .Where(conditionLambda) used the Where(IEnumerable) extension method, which is enumerate on the whole table in the memory. I think you get OutOfMemoryException because, this code tried to load the whole table to the memory (and of course created the objects). Am i right? Thanks :)

Comment: I think a simpler explination of @JohnPeters question was that under the covers LinqToSql is turning your lambda expression from the Linq .Where(x => x.Value > 30) to the Sql string "WHERE Value > 30" and passing it along to the database.  Expression<T> is the magic juju that lets that happen.

Comment: Is it possible to have a method for entity framework that takes a method with an Func<> but pass in an an object of type Expression<Func<,>> (expr) with the Compile() method... .i.e. - var results = repository.Find(expr.Compile()) ?  Or will is suffer the same performance ?

Comment: @bbqchickenrobot Types are important - the result of `Compile()` will be a `Func<>` so you are passing a `Func<>` to the `Find` method - no `Expression` is involved. So your performance will be terrible.

Answer (score 119):

There is a more philosophical explanation about it from Krzysztof Cwalina's book(*Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries*);

> [image: Rico Mariani]

**Edit for non-image version:**

> *Most times you're going to want **Func** or **Action** if all that needs to happen is to run some code. You need **Expression** when the code needs to be analyzed, serialized, or optimized before it is run. **Expression** is for thinking about code, **Func/Action** is for running it.*

Comment: Well put. ie. You need expression when you are expecting your Func to be converted into some sort of query. Ie. you need `database.data.Where(i => i.Id > 0)` to be executed as `SELECT FROM [data] WHERE [id] > 0`. If you just pass in a Func, you've put blinders on your driver and all it can do is `SELECT *` and then once it's loaded all of that data into memory, iterate through each and filter out everything with id > 0. Wrapping your `Func` in `Expression` empowers the driver to analyze the `Func` and turn it into a Sql/MongoDb/other query.

Comment: So when i am planning for a Vacation, I would use `Expression` but when I am ON vacation it will be `Func/Action` ;)

Comment: @ChadHedgcock This was the final piece I needed.  Thanks.  I have been looking at this for a while, and your comment here made all the study click.

Answer (score 116):

An extremely important consideration in the choice of `Expression` vs `Func` is that `IQueryable` providers like LINQ to Entities can 'digest' what you pass in an `Expression`, but will ignore what you pass in a `Func`. I have two blog posts on the subject:

[More on Expression vs Func with Entity Framework](http://fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/01/10/More-on-Expression-vs-Func-with-Entity-Framework.aspx) and
[Falling in Love with LINQ - Part 7: Expressions and Funcs](http://fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2011/12/02/Falling-in-Love-with-LINQ-Part-7-Expressions-and-Funcs.aspx) (the last section)

Comment: +l for explanation. However I get 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.' and had to use ForEach after fetching the results.

Answer (score 89):

I'd like to add some notes about the differences between `Func<T>` and `Expression<Func<T>>`:

- `Func<T>` is just a normal old-school MulticastDelegate;
- `Expression<Func<T>>` is a representation of lambda expression in form of expression tree;
- expression tree can be constructed through lambda expression syntax or through the API syntax;
- expression tree can be compiled to a delegate `Func<T>`;
- the inverse conversion is theoretically possible, but it's a kind of decompiling, there is no builtin functionality for that as it's not a straightforward process;
- expression tree can be observed/translated/modified through the `ExpressionVisitor`;
- the extension methods for IEnumerable operate with `Func<T>`;
- the extension methods for IQueryable operate with `Expression<Func<T>>`.

There's an article which describes the details with code samples: 
[LINQ: Func<T> vs. Expression<Func<T>>](http://ivanitskyi.blogspot.com/2013/06/linq-func-vs-expression.html).

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Nice list, one small note is you mention that the inverse conversion is possible, however an exact inverse is not. Some metadata is lost during the conversion process. However you could decompile it to an Expression tree that produces the same result when compiled again.

Answer (score 44):

LINQ is the canonical example (for example, talking to a database), but in truth, any time you care more about expressing *what* to do, rather  than actually doing it. For example, I use this approach in the RPC stack of [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) (to avoid code-generation etc) - so you call a method with:

```
string result = client.Invoke(svc => svc.SomeMethod(arg1, arg2, ...));
```

This deconstructs the expression tree to resolve `SomeMethod` (and the value of each argument), performs the RPC call, updates any `ref`/`out` args, and returns the result from the remote call. This is only possible via the expression tree. I cover this more [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/explaining-expression.html).

Another example is when you are building the expression trees manually for the purpose of compiling to a lambda, as done by the [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) code.

Answer (score 29):

When using LINQ-to-SQL, passing `Func<>`s into `Where()` or `Count()` is bad.  Real bad.  If you use a `Func<>` then it calls the `IEnumerable` LINQ stuff instead of `IQueryable`, which means that whole tables get pulled in and *then* filtered. `Expression<Func<>>` is significantly faster because it performs the filtering **on the SQL server** - especially so if you are querying a database that lives another server.

Comment: Does this apply to in-memory query as well?

Comment: @stt106 Probably not.

Comment: This is only true if you enumerate the list. If you use GetEnumerator or foreach you will not load the ienumerable fully into memory.

Comment: @stt106 When passed to the .Where() clause of a List<>, Expression<Func<>> gets .Compile() called on it, so Func<> is almost certainly faster. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/SequenceQuery.cs,6bf428aa1f6b9002,references

Answer (score 26):

The primary reason is when you don't want to run the code directly, but rather, want to inspect it. This can be for any number of reasons:

- Mapping the code to a different environment (ie. C# code to SQL in Entity Framework)
- Replacing parts of the code in runtime (dynamic programming or even plain DRY techniques)
- Code validation (very useful when emulating scripting or when doing analysis)
- Serialization - expressions can be serialized rather easily and safely, delegates can't
- Strongly-typed safety on things that aren't inherently strongly-typed, and exploiting compiler checks even though you're doing dynamic calls in runtime (ASP.NET MVC 5 with Razor is a nice example)

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on no.5

Comment: @uowzd01 Just look at Razor - it uses this approach extensively.

Comment: @Luaan I am looking for expression serializations but not able to find anything without a limited third party usage. Does .Net 4.5 support expression tree serialization?

Comment: @vabii Not that I know of - and it wouldn't really be a good idea for the general case. My point was more about you being able to write pretty simple serialization for the specific cases you want to support, against interfaces designed ahead of time - I've done just that a few times. In the general case, an `Expression` can be just as impossible to serialize as a delegate, since any expression can contain an invocation of an arbitrary delegate/method reference. "Easy" is relative, of course.

Answer (score 25):

You would use an expression when you want to treat your function as data and not as code.  You can do this if you want to manipulate the code (as data).  Most of the time if you don't see a need for expressions then you probably don't need to use one.

Answer (score 13):

Overly simplified here, but `Func` is a machine, whereas `Expression` is a blueprint. :D

Answer (score 2):

It’s good to know you can use `Func<TEntity, bool>` with `AsQueryable()` extension method like `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

```
Func<App, bool> filter = x => x.Alias.Contains("gan");
var query = dbSet.Where(filter).AsQueryable();
```

The query will not be executed until you use the execution methods like `Count()` or `ToList()`.

Comment: AsQueryable will not do the trick it will still pull all the records from db and then perform filtration.

Comment: @QaziAbdurrehman; Not agreed. The query will not be executed until you use the execution methods. You can test it.

Comment: I already faced a scenarion where a Func delegate is passing to Where that automatically calls IEnumerable Where method which will pull all records from DB.

Comment: @QaziAbdurrehman; please share the sample code

Comment: It is identical to the code you wrote above

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents...

1. `Func<T>` = A delegate/method that just gets executed, that all.
2. `Expression<Func<T>>` = It gets converted to another form. For example, LINQ to Entities where the expression is converted to the equivalent SQL queries.

Imagine it in a way that both look similar but the Expression is like a data structure and has the power of reflection. The compiler literally knows everything about it's signature and it's body (similar to class reflection). Using this knowledge, the expression is converted to some other form like LINQ is converted to SQL queries.

Now, there is another angle to it which deals with IQueryable behavior. It is recommended that you always pass `Expression` to `Where` or `Count` method of LINQ so that your query filter runs on the SQL server instead of pulling data in memory and then filtering it.