# Lambda expression common syntax

Tags: c#, lambda

Can I follow any simple synax or rules for building "lambda expression" in C#? I read some articles and understood what a lambda expression is, but if I have the general syntax or rules that would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways of expressing lambdas, depending on the exact scenario - some examples:

```
    // simplest form; no types, no brackets
    Func<int, int> f1 = x => 2 * x;
    // optional exlicit argument brackets
    Func<int, int> f2 = (x) => 2 * x;
    // optional type specification when used with brackets
    Func<int, int> f3 = (int x) => 2 * x;
    // multiple arguments require brackets (types optional)
    Func<int, int, int> f4 = (x, y) => x * y;
    // multiple argument with explicit types
    Func<int, int, int> f5 = (int x, int y) => x * y;
```

The signature of the lambda must match the signature of the delegate used (whether it is explicit, like above, or implied by the context in things like `.Select(cust => cust.Name)`

You can use lambdas *without* arguments by using an empty expression list:

```
    // no arguments
    Func<int> f0 = () => 12;
```

Ideally, the expression on the right hand side is exactly that; a single expression. The compiler can convert this to *either* a `delegate` *or* an `Expression` tree:

```
    // expression tree
    Expression<Func<int, int, int>> f6 = (x, y) => x * y;
```

However; you can also use statement blocks, but this is then only usable as a `delegate`:

```
    // braces for a statement body
    Func<int, int, int> f7 = (x, y) => {
        int z = x * y;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        return z;
    };
```

Note that even though the .NET 4.0 `Expression` trees support statement bodies, the C# 4.0 compiler **doesn't** do this for you, so you are still limited to simple `Expression` trees unless you do it "the hard way"; see [my article on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

A lambda expression is, fundamentally, a shorthand notation for a function pointer. More commonly, a lambda expression is the propagation of input data into an expression that computes a result. In most cases, you will use lambda expressions in their more common form:

```
int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 3, 11, 21, 9, 23, 7, 4, 18, 7, 7, 3, 21 };

var twentyoneCount = numbers.Where(n => n == 21).Count();
var sumOfgreaterThanSeven = numbers.Sum(n => n > 7 ? n : 0);
```

In their less common form, lambda expression can replace more cumbersome delegate forms:

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
// ...
void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Implement button click handler here
}
```

Or the less common, and less verbose:

```
myButton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Implement button click handler here
};
```

The following lambda expression achieves the same result as the above two:

```
myButton.Click += (s,e) =>
{
    // TODO: Implement button click handler here
};
```

The power of this latter form really comes from its capability to create closures. A closure is where you implement a function within a function, and "close" around parameters and variables from the parent function scope:

```
private void DoSomething(IList<string> input, SomeObject source)
{
    source.OnSomeEvent += (s,e) => return input.Sum();
}
```

Comment: Excellent .It exactly took me the real programming world. Thousand thanks to jrista

Comment: "A lambda expression is, fundamentally, a shorthand notation for a function pointer." Not necessarily. An important distinction and a crucial feature of lambdas is the ability to treat them as data (expression trees) rather than code (anonymous methods). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct/793584#793584

Comment: @Mehrdad: True, lambdas do initially become expression trees. However, the end result of evaluating an expression tree is evaluating a dynamic method, pointed to by a delegate. The expression tree is just the intermediate representation of the ultimate function pointer. Note the .Compile() method, which returns a delegate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx

Comment: jrista: But no-one forces you to call `.Compile()` on an expression tree. The canonical example is LINQ to SQL. It doesn't call compile on your expression tree and the end result is **not** a function. It's a generated SQL statement.

Comment: Mehrdad: Good point. In cases like L2S, you are absolutely right, they behave as expression trees in their entirety.