# What Is => Called and How Is It Used in C#

Tags: c#

I have seen => used in sample code, but I don't know what this operand is called. Because the term is just symbols, Google search is not very helpful.

Here is an example of its use:

```
var rolesAllowed = rolePermission.Where(permission => permission.Permissions.Any(p => Demand.HasFlag(p.Type))).ToList();
```

This question is different from the ones so brazenly marked as "duplicate". I was looking for the name of the expression so I could research how to use it. The so-called duplicate item was for someone who already knew that => was called a lambda expression.

I want to thank the people who took the time to read and understand the question, and post a quality response.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/does-symbol-mean-t3532445.html

Comment: Note that operators are searchable when you use quotes: `[C#] "=>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is used to for [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).  Essentially what that the Where function takes in is another function that iterates through the collection.  The left side of the => defines the parameters and the right side is the actual function that gets run.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if I was to translate my sample code into an English sentence, it would be "Look for permissions in the Permissions class where that class is flagged as a specific type of permission, place it in a list, and assign it to the rolesAllowed variable"?

Comment: That sounds like it describes the function above.

Answer (score 5):

It is called *[Lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)*

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any)
>   on the left side of the **lambda operator =>**, and you put the expression
>   or statement block on the other side. For example, the lambda
>   expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns
>   the value of x squared.

*Lambda expressions* use special syntax. They allow functions to be used as data such as variables or fields. The lambda expression syntax uses the `=>` operator. This separates the parameters and statement body of the *[anonymous function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx)*.

The `=>` operator can be read as **"goes to"** and it is always used when declaring a lambda expression.

Comment: I've always pronounced it as 'such that', but 'goes to' is also very nice, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx) and it's the part of the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) syntax.

Lambda expressions are very concise way to create [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Anonymous method example:

```
button1.Click += delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs e)
                   { MessageBox.Show("Click!"); };
```

The same code, but this time using lambda expression:

```
button1.Click += (o,e) => MessageBox.Show("Click!");
```

As shown, this syntax is a 
great shorthand notation for authoring anonymous methods, where a stack of arguments can be passed 
into a group of statements for processing. Any method in the .NET platform that takes a delegate object 
as an argument can be substituted with a related lambda expression, which will typically simplify your 
code base quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx), it creates a lambda expression, which is like an anonymous method.

Answer (score 1):

**=>** is a [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), check the link to read more.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552827/lambda-expression-common-syntax) answer for more details.