# Benefit of Expression<Func<T>> over Func<T>

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

Possibly my shortest ever SO question:

What is the benefit of declaring `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` over `Func<T, bool>`?

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct