# Create and Calling SqlFunctions in Linq to Entities C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, linq-to-entities, expression

We wanna create the following code dynamically with expression:

```
TestDatabaseEntities entities = new TestDatabaseEntities();
entities.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); // to show generated tsql
// We wanna create the following line dynamically
List<Employee> employees = entities.Employees.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)c.SomeNumber).Trim().Contains("123")).ToList();
```

Above code works great. now we wanna create it with expression dynamically.
We done it as follows :

```
Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

Type nullableDoubleType = typeof (double?);
//leftSile == {entity.SomeNumber}, it's OK
UnaryExpression unaryExpression  = Expression.Convert(leftSile, nullableDoubleType);
MethodInfo stringConvertMethodInfo = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new[] { nullableDoubleType });
MethodInfo trimMethodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[] {});
ConstantExpression newRightSide = Expression.Constant(valueObject.ToString());

var traceVariable1 = Expression.Call(stringConvertMethodInfo, unaryExpression);
var traceVariable2 = Expression.Call(traceVariable1, trimMethodInfo);
Expression resultExpression = Expression.Call(traceVariable2, methodInfo, newRightSide);
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(resultExpression, parameterExpression);

// expression == {entity => (StringConvert(Convert(entity.SomeNumber)).Trim().Contains("123"))}
```

The expression created successfully, but when we use it within EntityFramework it throws an exception:

```
List<Employee> employees2 = entities.Employees.Where(expression.Compile()).ToList();
//Exception :
//An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
//Additional information: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the solution :

We don't have to use `Compile()` by ourself. we wanna use the following code:

```
List<Employee> employees2 = entities.Employees.Where(expression).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below links

[Dynamic predicates for Linq-to-Entity queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087973/dynamic-predicates-for-linq-to-entity-queries)

[Dynamic Querying with LINQ-to-Entities and Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express)