# LINQ Select expression IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, select, expression

I'm trying to use an `Expression` inside of a `LINQ` `Select`. Here is an example of my code

```
Expression<Func<user, string>> expr = d => d.user.username;
Message.Select(b => new { name = b.user.Select(expr) });
```

Message is of type `IEnumerable`, at runtime i'm getting the following error :
`The exception message is ''System.Collections.Generic.List<W.Models.user>' does not contain a definition for 'Select'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are missing a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file. Note, though, that `List<T>` is LINQ-to-Objects; lose the `Expression`:

```
Func<user, string> expr = d => d.user.username;
Message.Select(b => new { name = b.user.Select(expr) });
```

Final thought; while the message about `System.Collections.Generic.List<W.Models.user>` suggests a list, your code (`b.User.Select` / `Message.Select`) suggests individual objects. This is ... confusing.

Comment: I'm using System.Linq and System.Linq.Expressions

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson did you see the edit about removing the `Expression` ? However, I think your best bet is to reduce this to a minimal ***runnable*** example. Chances are you'll find the problem while reducing it, but if you can't : people will be able to repro and fix it.

Comment: In DB, the table message has a relation to one-to-many relation to user, i'm trying to select all of the users for a message from a IEnumerable<dynamic> query containing the message. The Models.user is code first EF.

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson did the message perhaps *actually* say: `'System.Collections.Generic.List<user>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)' has some invalid arguments` ?

Comment: It only says System.Collections.Generic.List<W.Models.user>' does not contain a definition for 'Select', no innerException either.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct).

The accepted answer describes that `Func<T>` is a delegate to a method that returns a `T`. `Expression<Func<T>>` however is actually a **description** of how that delegate can be evaluated. You can for example [compile an expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb345362.aspx) into an actual delegate:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i < 5;
Func<int, bool> deleg = expr.Compile();
Console.WriteLine("deleg(4) = {0}", deleg(4));
```

You can even write:

```
Console.WriteLine("deleg(4) = {0}", expr.Compile()(4));
```

So if you really need an expression you need to compile it into the actual delegate otherwise use the delegate in the first place.

(BTW: Your code example won't compile since there is no `Select` method for a `List<user>` that takes an expression and also `d => d.user.username` is probably wrong. Since `d` is a `user` it should be `d => d.username`).

However linq to entities does not support delegate calls. Therefore you have to switch to **linq to objects** by adding `AsEnumerable()`:

```
Expression<Func<user, string>> expr = d => d.username;
Func<user, string> func = expr.Compile();

var result = context.Message.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(b => new { name = b.user.Select(func) });
```

Use linq to entities for accessing the data, simple ordering, filtering etc. This way it can optimize the queries for the database but then switch to linq to objects if you need more.

PS: The lambda `d => d.username` is compiled into a delegate. If you explicitly put it into the expression `b.user.Select(u => u.username)` it will work fine because now this also compiles into an expression that linq to entities can handle without calling a delegate.

Comment: The exception message is ''System.Collections.Generic.List<W.Models.user>' does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Comment: @TobiasOlofsson: `b.user` in your lambda is a `List<user>` and you pass an expression to its `Select` method. There is no `Select` method that takes an expression (unless you declared an extension method for `List<>`). So this cannot even compile. But even when you pass a `Func` linq to entities will fail because it can't execute the delegate (as I actually tested: "`Invoke` is not supported by EF").