# Practical implications of using Expression<T> in methods with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, implementation

Using `Linq.Expression<T>` types we can programmatically define AST for later evaluation and/or execution.

But in practical terms, what are the implications of defining the method signature in this way:

```
public void SomeMethod1(Func<bool> func) { ... } // 1.
```

instead of

```
public void SomeMethod2(Expression<Func<bool>> expr) { ... } // 2.
```

Clearly the way we get the result from `Func<bool>` varies from:

```
var result = func(); // 1.
```

to

```
var func = expr.Compile() // 2.
var result = func();
```

At raw practical level also invocation is similar:

```
SomeMethod1(() => true); // A.
SomeMethod1(() => AMethodReturnsABool()); // B.
SomeMethod1(AMethodReturnsABool); // C.
```

with the difference that `SomeMethod2` at compile level don't accept the *method-group* syntax:

```
//SomeMethod2(AMethodReturnsABool); // -> don't compile
```

When I need to define a signature with standard delegates `Action<T,...>` or `Func<T,..>` when I should define them inside an `Expression<T>`?

Comment: IMHO , Till you don't write a software which generates code by drag & drop. In most practical terms , you don't need it

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: @Fendy +1, thanks for the link. I've tried to search, but I missed this question.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. If you don't need to have access to the AST of your LINQ expression, use the compiled (anonymous delegate) version.

The cases that I think of where you may need to have access to the AST:

- Transforming the AST into something else, like an SQL where clause.
- Analyze some properties of the written code.
- Programatically build a delegate. For instance, build Expression<T> objects out of some user input. This can save the hassle of writing your own AST with its IL translator.
- Astracting your Data Access Layer to be able to use either LinqToSQL or a simple in-memory list with the same LINQ query specifications.

In short, if you don't need Expression<T>, don't use Expression<T>.