# Linq To SQL FirstOrDefault fetching all rows

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm making a generic repository and FirstOrDefault is not generating the sql query that I expect.

Below you can see the relevant part. If I for example use ".Find(x => x.Id == id);" on a table using this repo the generated sql is first fetching all the rows and the doing the firstordefault operation. Where as I would have expected it to generate an where clause.

Any ideas about what Im doing wrong?

```
public class Repo<T> : IRepo<T> where T : class
{
    protected SBContext Context { get; set; }

    public Repo(SBContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return Context.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    public T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `return DbSet.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, made no difference. Im using EF6 by the way, don't know if something has changed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your method signature to

`public T Find(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)`

Explanation:

In `System.Linq.Queryable`, there is an extension method with this signature:

`public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);`

and in `System.Linq.Enumerable`, there is an extension method with this signature:

`public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);`

When you specify that the Find method takes a `Func` then you are using the `Enumerable` extensions rather than `Queryable` extensions.

There is an implicit cast to an `IEnumerable<TSource>` when you pass the `IQueryable Context.Set<T>()` to the extension method as the  `source` parameter and when you cast `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` the expression is immediately evaluated and run against the database, the data is pulled into memory and you are now using Linq-to-Objects

References:

[Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

[Re-implementing Linq-To_Objects  - AsEmumerable()](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx)

Comment: Great, that did it! I suppose it has something to do with DbSet being a kind of repository in itself and not recognizing the context for the expression?