# NotifyOfPropertyChange for method groups?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

**Hey,**

short question:

I want to notify my ui, so my guard method is invoked once again.. But unfortunately I get an syntax-error using this statement:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanLogin);
```

My class inherits PropertyChangedBase.

**The error message:**

> The type arguments for method `'void
>   Calidburn.Miro:PropertyChangedBase.NotifyOfPropertyChange<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>>)'`
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Do I miss some overload or is something else wrong? What else could be the problem?

Comment: Yep, thats correct. Its a guard method.

Comment: How is `CanLogin` defined?

Comment: public bool CanLogin()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ip) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Port);
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you posted in your comment, I think your problem is that the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method is expecting you to pass a property, rather than a method.

So you'd want something like:

```
public bool CanLogin 
{ 
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ip) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Port); 
    }
}
```

I was going to write something about `Expression<Func<TProperty>>` to help explain the error message, but this answer does a fantastic job: [Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

Comment: Thank you Chris. :) Do you have any idea, why I never saw this solution? I mean, all the samples I saw on the internet were showing methods instead of properties :(

Comment: Hey, I'm actually not sure, I tried looking through the docs to see where you might find that out, but aside from http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions (search for `CanSayHello`) there isn't a huge mention of it. I've often made mistakes like making the property a field, or making it a method and then finding problems, so it's a common error =D

Comment: What is slightly odd, is that if I create a method, rather than a property, I get a slightly different error to yours =O

Comment: FYI: I havent started the program, I have just pointed my cursor at the underlined statement, so maybe thats why your msg differs from mine.

Comment: I get messages along the lines of `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`, glad it's fixed though =D