# EntityFramework 6.1.1 with Linq Performance issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework to select data from my mssql database. My query looks something like this:

```
int param = 123456;
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var query = context.Table.AsQueryable();
    var result = query.Where(o => o.Id == param).ToList();
}
```

This query takes about 10 seconds.

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var query = context.Table.AsQueryable();
    var result = query.Where(o => o.Id == 123456).ToList();
}
```

This query takes less than 1 second.

I just found out that EntityFramework generates two different queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name],  
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] DESC
-- p__linq__0: '2932323' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
[Filter1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 2932323 = [Extent1].[Id]
)  AS [Filter1]
WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Filter1].[Id] DESC
```

Is there a way to speed up the first one or another way to do it?

Comment: Could you show the queries that get generated for each one? Also, why aren't you querying the `context` directly? Why use `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: `AsQueryable()` is redundant in both cases

Comment: @haim770 Redundant, yes, but not problematic or harmful though.

Comment: the one with int parameter becomes a func<> instead of expression as the other one

Comment: @Servy: That's right, but why would one do that? That's right, but why would one do that?

Comment: @Andreas Well, it's not in the code shown.  If it was out of scope in the real code then it wouldn't compile, rather than being slow.

Comment: Does your program execute any EF code before that? EF takes some time for first query for initialization, so if your first sample is the first query that program executes, then it can be a reason for 10 seconds

Comment: sorry changed my comment :)

Comment: @Andreas Now the comment is still wrong; both of the queries in the code shown will compile into expressions, not delegates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct ,  are you sure?

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbd18f3c-8dfa-49a6-b57a-685a5f0d4098/linq-to-entities-with-variable-substitution-slow?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: imho this is about parameter sniffing. Try `EXEC sp_updatestats` on the database

Comment: It looks like you are referencing a ID. Is that a Primary Key? If so use FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I've already seen the MSDN article but Id and param are the same datatype

Comment: Id is not the PrimaryKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, seen the sql queries, this is not (only) an EF related performance problem, but an SQL server performance problem.

You should considers the following:

- as Id is not a PK: create an index on it;
- use `EXEC sp_updatestats` to update the statistics and help the db server to produce better execution plans.

btw: how long takes query 1 in SSMS ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

I dropped all execution plans using sp_recompile and now all is working fine.

Thx for your help.

P.

Comment: and the Query is still diffrent?  the one with parameter is still slower since EF produces weird sql

Comment: the queries are still the same. but both take the same amount of time