# Func<t, bool> vs Manually expression performance in C# lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, lambda

Please take a look at these lines:

**1. in this case I type where statement directly in method**

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
{
    return _entity.Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToList();
}
```

Executed sql query is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email],
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Account_Users] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Account_Profiles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
```

**2. in this case I used Func for generic where clause**

```
public List<User> GetUsers(Func<User, bool> where)
{
    return _entity.Where(where).ToList();
}
var users = _acc.GetUsers(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Executed sql query is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Account_Users] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Account_Profiles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]
```

as you can see, in case 2 where clause which is `WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]` is missing and therefore whole records are stored in memory. do you have any idea why where clause is not translated in sql query?

I want to use `Func<t, bool>` in `.Where()` so it would be generic and no need to create functions for each query.
is there any way to use `.Where(Func<t, bool>)` and also see the translated where clause in sql query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want your lambda to be executed in SQL, you need to pass it as an Expression, not a Function:

```
public List<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> where)
{
    return _entity.Where(where).ToList();
}
var users = _acc.GetUsers(x => x.Id == 1);
```

If you wonder what the difference is (after all, the lambda itself looks the same), take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct?rq=1).

Comment: that simple and I was wondering why my app is so slow... thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
public List<User> GetUsers(Func<User, bool> where)
```

you should be using

```
public List<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> where)
```

When you are using `Expression` Entity Framework is able to translate it to SQL correctly. On the other hand when you are using `Func` Entity framework doesn't know how to translate that to SQL so it is using in-memory processing.

Answer (score 3):

That is because in this two cases compiled code contains call to two different extension methods: [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) respectively. `Queryable` class contains extension methods for processing data from different data sources, including external sources whereas `Enumerable` contains extension methods for in-memory objects processing. `Queryable` version of `Where` accept `Expression` rather than `Func`.

Lamda expression can be implicitly converted to both `Expression` and `Func`, so as other answers pointed out you just need to accept an `Expression` instance as your function argument.