# understanding C# Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

I have googled a lot to understand the lambda expressions in c#. Though people have given a handful of information, I couldn't understand what it is. Can any one explain me with the following code. This code can give me the understanding, since it is "my" context.

```
context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
    new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Austen" },
    new Author() { Id = 2, Name = "Charles Dickens" },
    new Author() { Id = 3, Name = "Miguel de Cervantes" }
    );
```

Why it is not "x=>x" ?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx) for this method?

Comment: ... and also the documentation on [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty involving method for 'understanding' Lambda expressions and will require the understanding of expressions too. I would suggest looking at LINQ

Answer (score 4):

```
x => x
```

is a shorthand for

```
x => {
    return x;
}
```

which is a function that takes x as a parameter and returns x, while

```
x => x.Id
```

is a shorthand for

```
x => {
    return x.Id;
}
```

This basically means that the `AddOrUpdate` function needs to know how to get the Id of the entities it's adding or updating, you can think of lambdas as a compact way of defining functions, in most cases you can actually define a function:

```
int GetAuthorId(Author x) {
    return x.Id;
}
```

and use the function in place of the lambda:

```
context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(GetAuthorId,
    new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Jane Austen" },
    new Author() { Id = 2, Name = "Charles Dickens" },
    new Author() { Id = 3, Name = "Miguel de Cervantes" }
);
```

Inside the AddOrUpdate function, it will run the GetAuthorId passing an Author as a parameter whenever it wants to find an Author's Id

--EDIT--

As correctly noted in the comments, what I just said is true for `Func<>`, but is NOT true for `Expression<Func<>>` you can read a little about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

Comment: OP is probably referring to [IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846514(v=vs.103).aspx). If so, the first parameter is an expression, not a delegate, in which case, the lambda expression can't be substituted by a function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply stated, it's because the method is expecting to receive an expression that represents the semantic key for `Authors`.

Think of it like this - if you passed in `x => x`, you would be trying to perform the following operation:

1. Based upon the key specified by the object Author
2. Add or update the given `Author` objects.

Whereas when you pass in `x => x.Id`, you're saying:

1. Based upon the key specified by the object Author.Id
2. Add or update the given Author objects.

To understand why, it may help you note the method takes an `Expression<Func<TEntity,Object>>`. This parameter type is often use to perform operations upon an arbitrary property, like `AddOrUpdate` is doing here.

Here's an example of a method would takes a expression and prints out the member name of the property. There's a lot more power here, but this should atleast help explain why `AddOrUpdate()` takes the parameters it does.

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

static void Example<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> identifierExpression)
{
    MemberExpression prop = identifierExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    Console.WriteLine(prop.Member);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var person = new Person { FirstName = "jd", LastName = "phenix" };
    Example<Person>(x => x.FirstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Why it is not "x=>x"
```

Because the function wants sometime to uniquely identify each object.  In this case the **ID** of the object.

If the ID exists, an update is performed.  If the ID doesn't exist, an insert is performed.