# How to filter records from a db using linq expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression

I am trying to achieve the following pattern:

```
Main()
{
    ...
    GetFilteredUsersById(u => u >= 100 && u < 200).Dump();
    ....
}

public List<UserRecord> FilteredUsersById(Func<int, bool> filter)
{
    Expression<Func<UserRecord, bool>> filterExpression = x => filter(x.Id);
    return someUserRecordsDb.Where(filterExpression).ToList();
}

public class UserRecord
{
    public int Id;

    public string Name;
}
```

Of course, this fails with

> NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

I understand why the error is happening, but don't know how to fix it.

Below is a pattern that does work, but I'm interested in understanding what changes I need to make to the code to the first pattern above to make it work.

```
Main()
{
    ...
    GetFilteredUsersById(u => u.Id >= 100 && u.Id < 200).Dump();
    ....
}

public List<UserRecord> FilteredUsers(Expression<Func<UserRecord, bool>> filter)
{
    return someUserRecordsDb.Where(filter).ToList();
}

public class UserRecord
{
    public int Id;

    public string Name;
}
```

Thanks for answering my first question here at StackOverflow!

Comment: There is nothing you *can* do to make the first sample work. Think about it -- how is the LINQ code supposed to know what an arbitrary `Func<int, bool> filter` *contains* at runtime? It would have to decompile the actual IL in order to translate it to SQL! The second code works precisely because the code is *not* compiled to IL, but passed as an expression tree, which can be translated to SQL prior to execution.

Answer (score 0):

As already you know, LINQ to SQL works by taking your lambdas as expression trees instead of delegates. Then, it analyzes those trees and attempts to produce equivalent SQL code. Obviously, it can't support everything you can possibly write in C#.

In your second snippet, the LINQ provider sees an expression tree that contains this:

```
u => u.Id >= 100 && u.Id < 200
```

This is very easy to understand - it involves the `&&` operator, the `>=` operator and the `<` operator, all of which are known.

But in your first snippet, the LINQ provider sees an expression tree that contains this instead:

```
x => filter(x.Id)
```

This is very different, because it's an invocation of an arbitrary method that's not known to the provider. So now the provider has to look inside that method and see what it contains. If that method had another level of indirection, the provider would have to look even further. And so on.

If your expression tree requires that kind of work, the provider will refuse to do it. So any invocations to arbitrary methods will understandably fail.

Thus, the answer is simple: don't put a level of indirection between the location where you create the expression tree and the actual expression you want translated to SQL, otherwise the LINQ provider will reject it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to keep in mind here

**1. Expression vs Func**

One of the main things you need to understand is the difference between an `Expression` and a `Func` or any type of delegate type. In short the expression is passing a **tree representation** of the lamda, which can be translated into Sql.

There is a great answer that covers this in depth here : 
[Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

**2. Not all Expressions will Work with Linq-to-Sql**

Even if a function can be represented as an expression it does not mean that there will be a proper mapping from the operations being preformed in the lambda expression for the provider that is consuming your linq expression.

This is why you are getting the exception :

> NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

**Here even though it is a valid expression there is no way to convert the operation to sql** which is why you get an exception, even though `filter` would be a valid lambda if passed as an expression and called directly the translation of the statement is that it is trying to call this func `filter`, which doesn't map directly to anything in sql