# Use Entity Framework Select Single Row. Entity Framework did not generate sql statement right?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework as my data provider. And there is one specific table did not generate sql statement right.
While I have passed query condition, but the Entity Framework still generate sql statement for the whole table.

The Code is like this:

```
public IList<Device> GetDeviceByNodeId(string nodeId)
        => GetModels(device => device.DeviceNodeId == nodeId).ToList();

public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetModels(Func<T, bool> exp)
        => EntitySet.Where(exp);
```

And the generated sql statement is like :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[DeviceTypeId] AS [DeviceTypeId], 
[Extent1].[OriginalDeviceId] AS [OriginalDeviceId], 
[Extent1].[DeviceCode] AS [DeviceCode], 
[Extent1].[StatCode] AS [StatCode], 
[Extent1].[DevicePassword] AS [DevicePassword], 
[Extent1].[DeviceModuleGuid] AS [DeviceModuleGuid], 
[Extent1].[DeviceNodeId] AS [DeviceNodeId], 
[Extent1].[FirmwareSetId] AS [FirmwareSetId], 
[Extent1].[ProjectId] AS [ProjectId], 
[Extent1].[StartTime] AS [StartTime], 
[Extent1].[PreEndTime] AS [PreEndTime], 
[Extent1].[EndTime] AS [EndTime], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Extent1].[CameraId] AS [CameraId], 
[Extent1].[DomainId] AS [DomainId], 
[Extent1].[CreateDateTime] AS [CreateDateTime], 
[Extent1].[CreateUserId] AS [CreateUserId], 
[Extent1].[LastUpdateDateTime] AS [LastUpdateDateTime], 
[Extent1].[LastUpdateUserId] AS [LastUpdateUserId], 
[Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Extent1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled]
FROM [dbo].[Devices] AS [Extent1]
```

Did I use linq the wrong way ?

Comment: what is type of EntitySet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using a function, and not an expression.

Remember that `IQueryable`s are also `IEnumerable`s, so you are really calling `Enumerable.Where`, not  `Queryable.Where`. This will cause Entity Framework to execute the query and filter the results in memory.

Change your method signature from:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetModels(Func<T, bool> exp)
```

to

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetModels(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct) post for more information about the differences between Expressions and Functions.

Comment: No problem. Mark it as the answer please.