# Stuck on simple single param lambda with bool return value

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm stuck on a lambda with a single `int` parameter and a `bool` return value:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> myFunc = x => x == 5;
```

First, I tried this that returns a new `Func` that I can't make sense of; I was expecting a `true` boolean value:

```
var boolResult = Expression.Lambda(myFunc).Compile().DynamicInvoke(5);
```

Then I tried to explictly set the function parameters and return type instead:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>> (myFunc, param).Compile();
```

, but this throws an error:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression of type
>   'System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return
>   type 'System.Boolean'

Which is weird, but I tried to convert the expression:

```
var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>> (
    Expression.Convert(myFunc,
    typeof(Func<int, bool>))
    , param).Compile();
var boolResult = fn.Invoke(5);
```

, this however did not help and gives the same error:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression of type
>   'System.Func`2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return
>   type 'System.Boolean'

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you want to go with the Expression? For the function itself `Func<int, bool> myFunc = x => x == 5;` will do. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct) includng the comments!

Comment: @TaW I'm getting the Expression from another library that I have no control of, so that's sadly not an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your dynamic invocation code is the way in which you construct your lambda. When you pass `myFunc` as expression, you get a lambda that returns `Func<int,bool>`.

If you want to make a new `LambdaExpression` that takes `int` and return `bool`, you could harvest `Body` and `Parameters` of your `myFunc` object, like this:

```
var b = Expression.Lambda(myFunc.Body, myFunc.Parameters).Compile().DynamicInvoke(5);
```

or, since `myFunc` is already a `LambdaExpression`, you could compile it directly:

```
var c = myFunc.Compile().DynamicInvoke(6);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wlofIY)

Comment: And in case `myFunc` is strongly typed (as in the question `Expression<Func<int, bool>>`), there is no need for `DynamicInvoke` in the last example. You could just do `var c = myFunc.Compile()(6);`.