# Why use an Expression here, why not use a Func?

Tags: c#, expression

Suppose I have the following class...

```
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

...and I want to be able to check (separately) if the `Name` or `Nickname` properties start with an "a".

I could write two methods like this...

```
public bool NameStartsWithA(Person p) {
  return p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("a");
}

public bool NicknameStartsWithA(Person p) {
  return p.Nickname.ToLower().StartsWith("a");
}
```

However, this violates DRY (not a big issue in this artificially simple example, but could be significant in the real world).

Searching around, it seems that the answer to this is to do the following...

```
public bool StartsWithA(Person p, Expression<Func<Person, string>> f) {
  return f.Compile()(p).ToLower().StartsWith("a");
}
```

...which can then be called as follows...

```
bool b = StartsWithA(person, p => p.Name);
```

This works fine, but I want to know what the point of the `Expression` is. If I remove it, and make the method look like this...

```
public bool StartsWithA(Person p, Func<Person, string> f) {
  return f(p).ToLower().StartsWith("a");
}
```

...it seems to work just as well.

Is there any point to the `Expression`? Looking at "[Why would you use Expression> rather than Func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)" it seems that the `Expression` doesn't give me any benefit in this case (other than a weeny improvement in execution speed, which may or may not be significant depending on the scenario), as all I'm doing is executing it, not modifying it.

Comment: Doesn't `Expression<T>` just store data about the function? If you are not doing anything with the data then there is no reason to store it. There might be an advantage if you were to modify expression before compiling it.

Comment: If you're just going to compile the expression and call it, it would *probably* be better to take a delegate.

Comment: In this case, no there isn't any reason to use `Expression`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen By "take a delegate" do you mean use a `Func` (as in my second version), or did you mean something else? If something else, please could you clarify what, and why it would be better than the `Func`

Comment: Why must you use a Func at all? Can't you just call a static `StartsWithA(string)` and pass the property as a parameter?

Comment: @ChrisPickford Or just `person.Name.StartsWith("a")` and not even have a function

Comment: @ChrisPickford In this simple example, yes you could. My real use case is much more complex, and I couldn't do that. I needed to pass in something runnable that specified which property to use, as I needed to call that code against more than one object of the same type.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel sounds like you're over complicating what should be a trivial task. If you're passing in a reference to an object, and a delegate to select a property from that object type, then ipso facto you could just pass the property value.

Comment: Ahhhh!  Fingernails on a black-board.  if (p.Name[0].ToUpper() == 'A') { /* etc */ }.  Profiling your code so you'll get a sense of what is performant code is an important learning experience.

Comment: @HansPassant Didn't you read my original question? I pointed out that this was a stupidly simple example to demonstrate the question.

Comment: Oh, if only we could work from realistic examples.  "Yes you are right" can't be that helpful either.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I know what you mean, but it isn't that simple. I did try it that way originally, but it wasn't working, which is why I turned to this approach. Thanks for the comment though, I am as guilty of over complicating things as the next dev at times!

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel May I suggest that you revise your question to demonstrate the peculiarities of your code and why you are tied to the delegate approach?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I don't think it would help. The amount of code/text I would need to add would be significant, but the underlying issue (ie that I'm only executing the `Expression` not modifying it) would remain the same, so I don't think it would benefit anyone. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems that the Expression doesn't give me any benefit in this case

Yes you are right.

Normally `expression` is used when we want to play around with the body of the function that is passed in to the lambda expression, in normal cases where we just need to execute a method in memory on some data that is already in memory `Func` should be good to go.

In the post you referred in the question you can see the answer higlighting that it can be useful when implementing some data fetch logic in **Linq To Sql** or **Entity Framework** as they use `Expression` to inspect the information passed in and then translate it to the SQL statements.

From [Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793584/1875256) quoted:

> Conceptually, `Expression<Func<T>>` is completely different from `Func<T>`. `Func<T>` denotes a delegate which is pretty much a pointer to a method and `Expression<Func<T>>` denotes a tree data structure for a lambda expression. This tree structure describes what a lambda expression does rather than doing the actual thing.

So it's quite clear that how much these two are different and this should give you enough idea when to use which.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, and what the commenters on my question have confirmed.