# C# Mongo DB driver - expression with method call not working

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, linq-expressions, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to query some data and projecting to a class with fewer properties by sending an expression (C# mongo driver version 2.7.3).
I am trying to understand why a specific expression fails.
The failure greatly limits the user from writing a common projection and forces him to write the projection inline in every call.
This is a simplified example:

```
private IMongoCollection<MyOriginalClass> _collection;

class MyOriginalClass // imagine this class has many more properties
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

class MyProjectedClass
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

void DoWork()
{
  var data1 = GetData(lib => new MyProjectedClass { ID = lib.ID }); // succeeds
  var data2 = GetData(lib => ToProjected(lib)); // Fails in mongo driver: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index
}

IEnumerable<MyProjectedClass> GetData(Expression<Func<MyOriginalClass, MyProjectedClass>> projection)
{       
  return _collection
      .Aggregate()
      .Project(Builders<MyOriginalClass>.Projection.Expression(projection))
      .ToList();
}

MyProjectedClass ToProjected(MyOriginalClass orig)
{
    return new MyProjectedClass {ID = orig.ID};
}
```

Comment: Please familiarize with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: But the second one is still an Expression and not a Func (it's not compiled).

Comment: That's right. I've update my answer to be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First (succeeded) usage is an expression which mongo driver can look into at the runtime to become to know that ID = lib.ID. Specifically here is [NewExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2).

E.g. Visual Studio allow for expression visualization under debugger, and for first one it shows:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ConsoleApp1.Program+MyOriginalClass,ConsoleApp1.Program+MyProjectedClass]>(ConsoleApp1.Program+MyOriginalClass $lib)
{
    .New ConsoleApp1.Program+MyProjectedClass(){
        ID = $lib.ID
    }
}
```

Second (failed) usage is an expression with just a call to ToProjected, ToProjected is being compiled into IL, and at the runtime mongo driver cannot retrieve the knowledge that ID = lib.ID (at least not in such an easy way as with expressions). Specifically here is [MethodCallExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression?view=netframework-4.7.2). And the visualization of the second expression is:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ConsoleApp1.Program+MyOriginalClass,ConsoleApp1.Program+MyProjectedClass]>(ConsoleApp1.Program+MyOriginalClass $lib)
{
    .Call ConsoleApp1.Program.ToProjected($lib)
}
```

ToProject could be re-written as:

```
Expression<Func<MyOriginalClass, MyProjectedClass>> ToProjected()
{
    return lib => new MyProjectedClass { ID = lib.ID };
}
```

And used as:

```
var data2 = GetData(ToProjected());
```

Comment: So there is no difference between a compiled expression (Func) and a MethodCallExpression?  MethodCallExpression cannot be traversed?

Comment: Well it's kind of no difference, MethodCallExpression just calls a compiled code, as expression tree it's very shallow, and provides little info at the runtime. In contrast NewExpression could be a bigger expression tree with more info.
And yes, MethodCallExpression cannot be traversed (without decompiling)