# Is it possible to write Async IQueryable<TEntity> query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I would like to query my database table. I wonder if I can convert my query into IQueryable async.

Here is what I have,

```
var gameBankResult = await (context.GameBanks.Where(g => g.productCode == initiate.productCode)
                .Where(l => l.referenceId == null)
                ).ToListAsync();
```

How can I transform it into this?

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetManyQueryable(Func<TEntity, bool> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).AsQueryable();
        }
```

Comment: where is `TEntity` defined?

Comment: you can assume initiate is the entity @Jota.Toledo I would like to call it as follows `...await _unitOfWork.GameBankRepository.GetMany(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be passing around an `Expression` rather than a `Func`, otherwise Entity Framework will execute the query immediately, bringing the entire table into memory and filtering locally. For example:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetManyQueryable(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return dbSet.Where(where);
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct) for a good description of the difference.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yup, good point, I should have been more explicit.

Comment: How can I make the GetManyQueryable async?

Comment: It's returning an `IQueryable`, if you want async you need to materialise the data, for example with a `ToListAsync`. I would advise to not return the `IQueryable` in the first place.

Comment: Is this OK? `public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetGamesAsync(           Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where ) { return await dbSet.Where(where).ToListAsync(); }`

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "OK", but yes, that will work.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, when using `IQueryable<T>`, prefer expressions to delegates, i.e.

```cs
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetManyQueryable(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
{
    return dbSet.Where(where);
}
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
var query = whatever.Where(
    g => g.productCode == initiate.productCode && g.referenceId == null).ToListAsync();
```

but to be honest... that isn't much different to what you already have

Comment: Can I make it async? I am going to use this in my generic repository of asp.net web api solution.