# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on predicate

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, contains, predicate

I'm trying to find clients which fields have or contain something. Everything works if I hard code predicate, but when I pass predicate it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Repo code:

```
public IEnumerable<Contractor> Find(Func<Contractor, bool> predicate)
{
    var test = db.Contractors.Where(x => x.NIP.Contains("7822574676")).ToList(); //this is correct
    try
    {
        return db.Contractors.Where(predicate).ToList(); // this gives exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Service code:

```
public IEnumerable<ContractorShortDataDTO> FindByNIP(string NIP)
{
    try {
        return Database.Contractors.Find(x => x.NIP.Contains(NIP)).Select(x =>
            new ContractorShortDataDTO()
            {
                NIP = x.NIP,
                CompanyName = x.CompanyName,
                ID = x.ID
            }).AsEnumerable();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            return null;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Has `NIP` even got a value?

Comment: @JamesS yes sir

Comment: And on what line is this error thrown?

Comment: @JamesS 'return db.Contractors.Where(predicate).ToList();'

Comment: If you simplify this to just use a string Predicate then it all works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dtwZ5g

Comment: Because you have `Func<Contractor, bool> predicate`, the entire table is fetched on the client and then filtered, which means rows with null `NIP` will throw on `NIP.Contains()`. You are supposed to have `Expression<Func<Contractor, bool>>` to have it translated to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the argument in the method from

```
Func<Contractor, bool> predicate
```

to

```
Expression<Func<Contractor, bool>> predicate
```

See also related question [Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793571/1260204)