# How does @Html.TextBoxFor know that I am referring to the property of the model instead of the value returned by the property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Normally in lamda a expression such as 
`(x => x.FirstName)` the lamda would return the value of "FirstName" (presumably a string) but some how
`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)` knows that I am referring to the property "FirstName" and not the value returned by FirstName. What C# or compiler technique is being used for achieve this? I tried reading through the MVC source code but it went over my head.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here?

Comment: Simply put, it parses the lambda expression to see what property is being referenced.

Comment: TextBoxFor receives an Expression, rather than a Func ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) .. checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct on func vs expression

Comment: This sort of question makes me think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/226912).  Is there a different problem you're having and are attempting to handle by implementing this behavior? And are thus looking for guidance in that respect?

Comment: I am new to ASP.Net MVC and while reading a chapter on helper methods I couldn't wrap my head around how the compiler was determining the difference between the reference to the property vs it's return value. John Wu's answer below fixed me right up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Expression` is just an object representing what is contained in the lambda expression. It can be inspected like any other object. You can think of it as a complicated sort of Reflection, and indeed you can get things like `Type` and `PropertyInfo` for anything inside it, if you know how to parse it.

This example demonstrates how a simple expression like `m => m.FirstName` can be parsed to find out what property is being referenced:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName { get { return "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"; } }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        var result = Test(m => m.FirstName, model);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static TOut Test<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression, TIn instance) where TOut: class
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        var member = memberExpression.Member;

        Console.WriteLine("The expression is a reference to '{0}.{1}'", member.DeclaringType.FullName, member.Name);

        var compiled = expression.Compile();
        var result = compiled(instance) as TOut;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The expression is a reference to 'Example.MyModel.FirstName'
John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt
```

[Link to DotNetFiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Us1BGQ)

Comment: Thank you, I was missing that the lamba was inside an Expression object and how Expression object works.