# In Entity Framework Core, how can I query data on joined tables with a condition at DB level (not local LINQ)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, orm

As part of a small .NET Core 3 project, I'm trying to use the data model based in Entity Framework, but I'm having some troubles related with queries on joined tables.

When looking for data matching a condition in a single table, the model is easy to understand

```
List<Element> listOfElements = context.Elements.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

However, when this query requires joined tables, I'm not sure how to do it efficiently. After some investigation, it seems that the include (and theninclude) methods are the way to go, but I have the impression that the Where clause after the include is not executed at DB level but after all the data has been retrieved. This might work with small datasets, but I don't think it's a good idea for a production system with millions of rows.

```
List<Element> listOfElements = context.Elements.Include(x => x.SubElement).
    Where(predicate).ToList();
```

I've seen some examples using EF+ library, but I'm looking for a solution using the nominal EF Core. Is there any clean/elegant way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: How is your `predicate` defined?

Comment: Func<Element, bool> predicate = f => f.ElementType == elementType where elementType is a string parameter

Comment: It should be `Expression<Func<Element, bool>> predicate`. Otherwise, it would only match `Enumerable.Where()` (which is Linq-to-Objects - In memory) instead of your desired `Queryable.Where()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: @haim770 I believe you are right if you don't use the Queryable.Where() the filter will be executed in memory as opposed to being executed in the database.

Comment: As @haim770 commented, the solution was adding the "Expression" before for accessing the Queryable.Where instead of the Enumerable.Where. Thanks! If you want, add it as an answer as it's the actual solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few scenarios when the data from DB is populating:

- Deferred query execution: this is when you try to access your query results, for example, in the `foreach` statement.
- Immediate Query Execution: this when you call `ToList()` (or conversions to other collections, like `ToArray()`).

I think the answer's to your question:

> ... but I have the impression that the Where clause after the include is not executed at DB level but after all the data has been retrieved.

is that your assumptions are wrong because you are calling `ToList()` at the end, not before the `Where` method.

For more information please also check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution).

---

I've another suggestion also: to be sure about what is exactly executing at the DB level run [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) when executing your query.

Hope this will help ))

Comment: As mentioned by @haim770 in the comments of the original post the assumptions are not wrong since given the predicate used the Where() method used is not Queryable.Where() method which will make it so that the query is executed locally with everything in memory instead of in the database itself

Comment: As @haim770 mentioned, the problem was on which Where method was being used, Enumerable instead of Queryable.

Comment: @Rhadamon, sorry for the confusion. Actually that is correct. In the case of Enumerable `Where` will be used, the data manipulation will happen at the memory level. However, you were mentioning such a method as [Include](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1.include?view=netframework-4.8), which, if applied to DB Context, will work with Database queries (`IQuerable`) level. Please take my answer as connected to that specific case, because, for the situations with ordinary memory collection, you shouldn't worry about `Where` clause execution order.