# => Lambda operator in C#, how does it work here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, lambda

I am new to C# and I'm not sure I understand this piece of code:

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isAlive)`

From what I searched online, the lambda operator would be shorthand for a function such as
`parameter => expression`.

- Is this what is being used here?
- If so, is the function being called automatically since it has no name?
- Is a model object being implicitly passed in the 'model' parameter?

This is the full code:

```
@model IEnumerable<FirstMVC.Models.PersonModel> //retrieving the passed list (people) object, it becomes IEnumerable

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListPeople";
}

<h2>ListPeople</h2>

<p> <!--Here, only 2 params because it's assuming using PeopleController-->
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th><!--Displays column NAMES, notice DisplayNameFor-->
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isAlive)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td> <!--Displays row VALUES-->
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isAlive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would you use Expression<Func<T>> rather than Func<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)

Comment: A little demo to show that `Expression` can be used to view the content of the lambda: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fUCMn9. In your case the framework uses the structure generated by the expression to extract the property name so they can then use that to generate a display for that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this what is being used here?

Yes, it is defining an expression to be used

> If so, is the function being called automatically since it has no name?

No. Just the *expression* is being passed, not the *result* of that expression. In this case, the expression itself is never called - it is just analyzed to determine what member is being referenced (the `isAlive` property in this case) so that the input can be created, named, and bound to the member on callback.

> Is a model object being implicitly passed in the 'model' parameter?

A model is not being "passed", but the Razor compiler will use the type defined in the `@model {typename}` directive to determine the *type* of the `model` parameter.

Comment: Thank you that was clear. Could you just clarify where is the ```<%model...%>``` directive you speak of which defines the type used?

Comment: It should be at the top of the Razor page. And I had the syntax wrong, it should be `@model MyApp.MyModel`