# Example usage FirstOrDefaultDynamic with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I'm using VB in a project, together with EF.PLUS https://entityframework-plus.net/

I want to use `FirstOrDefaultDynamic`, but I didn't found any example for usage in VB - all examples are in C#.

Specifically I have an array of array of strings, and I want to find an element in it:

```vb
dim a = {
    {"a", "a1"},
    {"b", "b1"},
    {"c", "c1"}
}

dim elem = a.FirstOrDefaultDynamic("x(0) = y", new with {y="a"})
```

But I get error on evaluating the expression.

`FirstOrDefaultDynamic` accepts only string expression as parameter, not predicate (function).

The C# example is

```cs
var list = ctx.WhereDynamic(x => "x > 2").ToList();
```

but it still accepts a function returning an string expression which is to be evaluated.
Any idea on the VB syntax?

Comment: The C# example uses `WhereDynamic`. Do you have a C# example that uses your `FirstOrDefaultDynamic`?

Comment: No, but the WhereDynamic call in VB also accepts only string argument, so what should work for  WhereDynamic  should work for FirstOrDefaultDynamic as well

Comment: I don't see how, given the text of the error message that you have quoted. `x => "x > 2"` is `Function(x) "x > 2"` in VB, which is the opposite of "accepts only string expression as parameter, not predicate".

Comment: Could be that you misunderstood the message, as `x => "x > 2"` can be [either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793571/11683) `Func<T,string>` or `Expression<Func<T,string>>`.

Comment: Possible. Still it requires the parameter as string. Any idea how to write the condition I need as Expression<Func<T,string>> in VB?

Comment: It's `Function(x) "x > 2"` like I said.

Comment: I tried, but it cannot compile. The error is  something like "Delegate cannot convert to string"

Comment: Then it does not expect a function in the first place, which is not what the C# example does, like I originally noted.

Comment: Maybe you should start with a type that implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I did it with a strongly typed array and normal FirstOrDefault, but I was curious how this can be implemented the way I described here with a dynamic object

Comment: Well, not by LINQ, just classic for loops. Multi-dimensional arrays don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, the prerequisite for LINQ.

Comment: It might help to look at how the `...OrDefaultDynamic` extension methods are declared.  What is the type of the argument?  The Object Browser window might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

Only the C# syntax is supported.

So if you want to use any `Dynamic` method such as `FirstOrDefaultDynamic` from this library, you will need to stick with the C# syntax.

There is no plan to support `VB` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer from  [Jonathan Magnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619143/jonathan-magnan) :

The expression string used as parameter should use C# syntax, even if the call is made from VB.

Usage example:

```
Dim elem = a.FirstOrDefaultDynamic("x => x[0]=y", New With {.y = "MyTestVal"})
```