# The LINQ expression 'FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In seeding, I use a collection of Jsons to read it and insert it in DB.

I using this function

```
private void Seed<T, T2>(DbSet<T> dataSet, Func<T, T2> uniquProperty) where T : class, ISeedableEntity<T>
{
    var separtor = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var tableName = Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).SqlServer().TableName;
    var baseDir = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(baseDir);
    var filePath = $"{baseDir}{separtor}Data{separtor}{tableName}.json";
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(data);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var found = dataSet.Where(
                a => uniquProperty(a).Equals(uniquProperty(item))).FirstOrDefault();

            if (found != null)
            {
                found = found.Update(item);
                dataSet.Update(found);
            }
            else
                dataSet.Add(item);
        }
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And call it as this code.

```
Seed(CreditRatings, a => a.Id);
```

Comment: `Func<T, T2> uniquProperty` needs to be an `Expression` | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct

Comment: `a => uniquProperty(a).Equals(uniquProperty(item))` is the problem, EF (I assume you are using it) will not be able to translate `uniquProperty` call into SQL. You need to change `uniquProperty` parameter to `Expression<Func<T, T2>>` and build whole expression for `Where` from it.

Comment: what about foreach and check every item in expresstion

Comment: @MenaSamer - you shouldn't do it this way, because with the foreach you are than loading everything from the database into your local memory, and evaluate it locally, but instead you should use expression to let the evaluation happen on the database server - imagine you have millions of records with the foreach you would load each and every row, every row would need to move from database server to your local machine, eg. over the internet or intranet, it would need to be transformed from a database reader to an object (materialized) and than finally evaluated, so please use an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (I believe) is in the `uniqueProperty` delegate, which is declared as a `Func` delegate. LINQ cannot translate compiled functions into parts of the SQL instruction, and therefore gives up the effort, letting the predicate resolve at the calling end.

The direct result of such unfortunate even is that all the data from the database would be transferred to the caller prior to subduing them to the function.

You may try by accepting an expression evaluating to `bool` in place of the `Func` delegate.

```
private void Seed<T, T2>(DbSet<T> dataSet, Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> predicate)
where T : class, ISeedableEntity<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

The predicate would have to complete comparison of unique properties:

```
Expression<Func<T, T, bool>> seed = (a, b) => a.Id.Equals(b.Id);
```

It is probably possible to incorporate an expression which isolates an equatable property as well, and then to perform the equality test directly in the `Where` clause, but that would require a bit more work.